# Inhomogenous Euler-Cauchy ODE with small parameter $\epsilon$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in the following non-homogeneous Euler-Cauchy ODE
$$ x^2 y’’(x) + x y’(x) – y(x) = f(x) $$
where $$f(x) = - \epsilon  x^2 e^{- \epsilon x}$$
In the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ the ODE converges to the homogeneous case.

As a matter of fact, I would be already content with an approximation for $\epsilon \ll 1$, yet I thought I will first try to wrestle the exact solution.

The solution $y_0$ of the homogenous equation is given by $$y_0 = u_1 + u_2 = c_1 x + c_2 \frac{1}{x} $$ with $c_1,c_2$ constants to be considered later (on physical grounds I am looking for solutions such that $y(0) = 0$).

Next, I look for a particular solution via variation of parameters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters, 
$$ y_p = A(x) c_1 x + B(x) c_2 \frac{1}{x} $$
The functions $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are given by
$$ A(x) = \int -\frac{1}{W} u_2 f(x) \mathrm{d}x $$ and 
$$B(x) = \int \frac{1}{W} u_1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x $$
The Wronskian $W$ of the solutions to the homogeneous equation is gven by $$ W = -\frac{2}{x}$$
Courtesy of Wolfram Alpha, $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are computed as follows
$$ B(x) = - \frac{c_1 }{2} \frac { e^{- \epsilon x} (\epsilon^4 x^4 + 4 \epsilon^3 x^3 + 12 \epsilon^2 x^2 + 24 \epsilon x + 24    )} {\epsilon^4}$$ and
$$ A(x) = \frac{c_2 }{2} \frac { e^{- \epsilon x} (\epsilon^2 x^2 + 2 \epsilon x +2    )} {\epsilon^2}$$

I believe my general solution should now be 
$$y (x) = y_0(x) + A(x)c_1 x + B(x) c_2 \frac{1}{x} $$

But there must be mistakes as the general solution does not converge to the homogeneous equation solution $y_0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks as usual

Comment: Maybe you entered something into W.A. incorrectly. Because if we let $\epsilon \to 0$ in $A$ and $B$ before you integrate, we clearly get 0.

Comment: @Gregory, thanks for underlying that, I was actually pondering about it. For example, let me consider the integral $\int x e^{-\epsilon x} \mathrm{d}x$. For $\epsilon = 0$, it equals $\frac{x^2}{2}$. But W.A. gives me $- \frac{e^{-\epsilon x} (\epsilon x+1)}{\epsilon^2}$, must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: It also gives a series expansion around $0$ as  $-\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{x^2}{2} + \dots$

Comment: I am losing the little certainties I had. $\int e^{cx} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{c} e^{cx}$, and does not converge to $x$ as $c \to 0$ ,$e^{cx} \approx 1 + cx $ for small arguments. Oh my...Might better take a break.

Comment: Ok. Tha was momentarily scary, the reason behind the error is you have to be careful when using an indefinite integral. Consider the difference
$$ \int_0^x e^{c t} \, dt = \frac{e^{cx} - 1}{c}.$$
This converges to the correct value. So with the indefinite integral, the constant of integration is needed.

Comment: the solution is given by $$y(x)=\frac{c_1 \left(x^2+1\right)}{2 x}+\frac{i c_2
   \left(x^2-1\right)}{2 x}+\frac{e^{-x \epsilon } (x
   \epsilon +1)}{x \epsilon ^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner this blows up as $\epsilon \to 0$ and it shouldn't.

Comment: ok since the $\epsilon$ is located in the denominator?

Comment: Correct. It should agree in the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous solution is
$$ y_0 = c_1y_1 + c_2y_2 $$

where $y_1 = x, y_2 = {1\over x}$

The general solution is given by 
$$ y(x) = y_0 + Ay_1 + By_2 = (c_1 + A)y_1 + (c_2 + B)y_2 $$

where $A$ and $B$ are given by

$$ A'(x) = -{1\over W}y_2 f(x) $$
$$ B'(x) = {1\over W}y_1 f(x) $$

The integration constant is arbitrary since $y_0$ will take care of them, so we just need to pick constants that let $A,B \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$

$$ A(x) = \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}e^{-\epsilon x}(\epsilon^2x^2 + 2\epsilon x + 2) - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} $$
$$ B(x) = -\frac{1}{2\epsilon^4}e^{-\epsilon x}(\epsilon^4x^4 + 4\epsilon^3x^3 + 12\epsilon^2x^2 + 24\epsilon x + 24) + \frac{12}{\epsilon^4} $$